# Webpy and Facebook Graph API

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I am writing a simple python web service to get content out of Facebook Graph API. Now while testing I had written everything together in one single python class and it was working fine. Now that I have started modularizing everything that it all fell apart.

I am using webpy for my RESTful service. And my code looks somewhat like this:

*webapp.py*

```
import web
import FBModule

fb = FBModule.FBManager()

urls = (
    '/', 'HomeHandler',
    '/auth/login', 'LoginHandler',
    '/auth/logout', 'LogoutHandler'
)

class BaseHandler():
        def current_user(self):
            if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
                    self._current_user = dict()
                    user_id = web.cookies().get('fb_userid')
                    user_name = web.cookies().get('fb_username')
                    if user_id and user_name:
                        self._current_user = {'id': user_id, 'name': user_name}
            return self._current_user

class HomeHandler(BaseHandler):
        def GET(self):
            return render.oauth(current_user=self.current_user())


class LoginHandler:
    def GET(self):
        fb.login()      
        return web.seeother('/')

class LogoutHandler():
        def GET(self):
            fb.logout()
            web.seeother('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()
```

*FBModule.py*

```
import urllib
import urlparse
import time
import web

FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "<APP ID>"
FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "<APP SECRET>"

def path_url():
    return "http://localhost:8080" + web.ctx.fullpath

class FBManager:
    def login(self):
        data = web.input(code=None)
        args = dict(client_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID, redirect_uri=path_url())
        if data.code is None:
            return web.seeother('http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' + urllib.urlencode(args) + '&scope=' + urllib.quote('user_likes,friends_likes,user_birthday,friends_birthday'))
        args['code'] = data.code
        args['client_secret'] = FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET

        response = urlparse.parse_qs(urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(args)).read())
        access_token = response["access_token"][-1]
        profile = json.load(urllib.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,birthday,location,gender&" + urllib.urlencode(dict(access_token=access_token))))
        web.setcookie('fb_userid', str(profile['id']), expires=time.time() + 7 * 86400)
        web.setcookie('fb_username', str(profile['name']), expires=time.time() + 7 * 86400)

    def logout(self):
        web.setcookie('fb_userid', '', expires=time.time() - 86400)
            web.setcookie('fb_username', '', expires=time.time() - 86400)
```

The issue is that if I use a separate module to get the access token from Facebook, I get a "Corrupted Content Error". But if I do something as simple as cut and paste everything from the FBModule's login() function to the GET() function of the LoginHandler class, everything is hunky dory again. I am at my wits end trying to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Please let me know if you know what I am doing wrong.

Regds,
Paritosh

Comment: Well I got my answer. :) I was trying to redirect the browser too many times at once. I moved the return web.seeother('/') from GET function of LoginHandler to the login() function and it worked.